# MATLAB parallel reduction using parfeval

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, large-data

I want to compute the sum of many large matrices in parallel. However, using `parfeval`, the matrices are getting  buffered which yields a very high memory usage.

This is my current approach:

```matlab
N = 50;

p = gcp('nocreate');
if isempty(p)
    p = parpool('local', 4);
end

A_total = zeros(500, 500, 500);
for i = 1:N
    % do things
    pause(rand() * 0.05);
    
    f(i) = parfeval(p, @get_matrix, 1);
end

for i = 1:N
    [completed_index, A] = fetchNext(f);
    f(completed_index) = []; % drop future to reduce memory
    
    A_total = A_total + A;
end

function A = get_matrix()
    A = rand(500, 500, 500);
end
```

Even though I limit the number of parallel executions, the memory usage is still very high as the matrices are stored temporarily until they are fetched using `fetchNext()`. Is it possible to use `afterEach(f)` to add the generated matrix to `A_total` immediately after the execution was completed?

Another approach would be to check the number of unread futures in the first `for` loop and if this number exceeds a threshold, the data must be fetched first to limit the memory usage.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use parfeval for this? parfor or spmd should make it easier to manage the memory.

Comment: The "do things" part must be called sequentially. The data that is generated there can then be processed in parallel using `parfeval`. I basically want to trigger the processing without blocking the execution of the for loop.